# In Python, how do you identify a directory where the name includes a period?

Tags: python, directory, os.path

Under Windows, suppose you have the following directory:

```
r:\glew-1.10.0
```

What Python method can be used to reliably identify that this is a directory?

```
os.path.isdir("r:\\glew-1.10.0")  # returns false
os.path.isfile("r:\\glew-1.10.0") # returns true

mode = os.stat("r:\\glew-1.10.0").st_mode
stat.S_ISDIR(mode)       # raises a WindowsError - the system cannot find the file
```

It seems clear that the presence of a period in the directory name is causing the problem with these functions, but I can't find any alternatives.

Comment: "It seems clear that the presence of a period in the directory name is causing the problem with these functions" ... Maybe it's because I'm not looking at your file system, but that doesn't seem clear to me...

Comment: I don't think it's the periods. Maybe the backslashes.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually a directory, and not an NTFS 6-style soft link or a junction point or even an old-school Explorer shortcut? (Support for the first two has been added in more recent versions of Python, but I don't know which version you're using; shortcuts just _are_ regular files, so Python will never add fully-transparent support for them, because that would be wrong.)

Comment: If I remove the periods from the folder name, the functions work correctly. But I stumbled across this while trying to write something generic, so renaming folders isn't really an option.

Comment: Work fine for me with Python 2.7.8 on my Windows box.

Comment: For me as well, but python 3.4

Comment: On the commnad line, try `dir r:\`. It'll tell you if its not a regular directory.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7 and on my Windows 7 box with a directory named exactly the same as yours I get a `true` from `isdir` and `false` from `isfile`. What version of Pythin do you have?

Comment: My face is red. I extracted this from a longer program (where I was experiencing the problem), and in creating my test program I managed to change the directory name to something incorrect. I still have a problem with the original program, but I think it is something unconnected, and quite possibly an error in my own code. :(

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own ineptness...

First, the concrete:

```
isdir(path)
```

will simply return False if the path doesn't exist (it *won't* raise an error).

Then the abstract:

If a search on Stack Exchange or Google doesn't reveal anyone else who mentions any problem similar to the one you have encountered, double-check your code. Unless you are doing something obscure, the chances are good that you just made an error yourself.